# multi query a dataframe table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

| student_id | gender | major | admitted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35377 | female | Chemistry | False |
| 56105 | male | Physics | True |

etc.

How do I find the admission rate for females?

I have tried:

```
df.loc[(df['gender'] == "female") & (df['admitted'] == "True")].sum()
```

But this returns an error:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Comment: `((df['gender'] == "female") & df['admitted']).sum()`?

Comment: What do you mean by admission rate ?  Just the count or the relative percentage ?

Comment: @SeaBean so all the females where admitted == True

Comment: actually @BigBen suggestion worked - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the last column is Boolean. can you try this

```
df[df['gender'] == "F"]['admitted'].sum()
```

Comment: So because 'admitted' is Boolean a =='True' is not required because 'admitted' = 'true' anyway ?

Comment: yes. you can filter using col==True and then using len() like len(df[(df['A'] == "F") & (df['B' == True)]). But we have one boolean column , we can use sum to get the count. sum will consider True as 1 and False as 0 . If we did not have any boolean column [or flag column with 1/0]  , then we had to use len one.

Comment: You should be using `.loc` here to avoid using chained indexing: `df.loc[df['gender'] == 'female', 'admitted'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `.loc` and use this code: `df[(df['gender'] == "female") & (df['admitted'] == "True")].sum()`

Comment: thanks but I get:     /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py:1167: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  result = method(y)

Comment: and also: TypeError: invalid type comparison